# Input field values not adding up correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript's Math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

I'm attempting to add up three input fields, each containing a value of 33.3 which should total 99.9, however they are totaling to 99.89999999999999

Could someone explain how this is happening. Below is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
$("#modify-funding input.percentCalc").sumValues()

$.fn.sumValues = function () {
    var sum = 0;
    this.each(function () {
        sum += $(this).fieldVal();
    });
    return sum;
};

$.fn.fieldVal = function () {
    var val;
    if ($(this).is(':input')) {
        val = $(this).val();
        alert("val " + val);
    } else {
        val = $(this).text();
    }       
    return parseFloat(('0' + val).replace(/[^0-9-\.]/g, ''), 10);
};
```

Comment: Floating point numbers are approximations, minor errors are part and parcel.

Comment: This somehow reminds me of Jon Skeet's [OMG Ponies!!! (Aka Humanity: Epic Fail)](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx). You know how [IEEE 754 floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#IEEE_754:_floating_point_in_modern_computers) work right? Yeah, the precision is that of the closest binary value in binary16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of floating point numbers. Floating points are aproximations of the number you want to represent. Thus when you save a number as `33.3` it is around but not exactly `33.3` this error adds up after multiple operations. The best way to compare floats is to not test for equality but to test weather they are in a range.

Instead of

```
if(x == 99.9)
```

try

```
if(Math.abs(99.9 - x) < .1)
```

If you just want the string representation. You could try handing the floating point number as an integer. i.e. `33.3` equals `333` then when you are turning it back into a string you add the decimal back in where appropriate. This would be the best solution for your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your solution, how would I work that in my js?

Comment: See my updated answer for a better solution to your specific problem